# JMeter does not see custom listener

Tags: java, swing, jmeter

I'm developing custom listener for JMeter.

The problem is that listener works fine on my machine and it does not appear in "Listeners" list with no errors in logs&console at another machine.

- My configuration: Win7-32bit, JMeter 2.7
- Another configuration: Mac OS X 10.8_x86_64, JMeter 2.7

What should I check to clarify this?
Can you give me starting point for further investigations of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution. The issue was that I've build Listener with Java 1.7 and tried to use ti with Java 1.6.
  After re-building with Java 1.7 listener works fine.